# venue_new "address" parameter, or "adress"?

Tags: eventbrite

Is the parameter spelled "**adress**" or "**address**"?

Here's the API doc: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/venues/venue_new/

Where it says:

```
address    The venue adress (line 1).
```

I ask this question because I'm porting some code, and it looks like we have been using "adress" and from looking at various github repos, it looks like this is considered one of the "inconsistant" variable naming issues related to this API.

*I know the misspelled parameter is working.*

I want to use the API correctly if I can, and would like to use "address" and just want confirmation that the it will indeed work, and that "adress" only works to be backwards compatible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question!

I fixed the 'adress' spelling typo, but the older spelling of this input label is still allowed (in order to ensure backwords compatibility with existing apps).

We don't have any plans to drop support for the older, misspelled attribute name - but, if you are revisiting old code, it won't hurt to fix the typo on your end as well.

The change should help ensure that the [venue object](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/venues/)'s schema / attribute names remain consistent on input and output.

Comment: Yay! I happen to already know that it works because I've been testing today. But I appreciate the ability to mark this as the answer.